# Spring-boot with Liquibase Overloading Property

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I am using *Spring boot* and *Liquibase*.
Using this url as guidelines

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

In `pom.xml`, the below entry is present so that spring boot knows about *liquibase*.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and put the changelog file in resources folder.
db.changelog-master.xml

Now Spring boot first tring to find db.changelog-master.yaml in classpath and throwing the exception like this.

Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml

To Fix the Issue, I have added the bean like below in my class and tried to set changeLog proprty.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleDataJpaApplication {


@Autowired
LiquibaseProperties properties;
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    properties.setChangeLog("classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml");
    liquibase.setChangeLog(this.properties.getChangeLog());
    liquibase.setContexts(this.properties.getContexts());
    liquibase.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
    liquibase.setDefaultSchema(this.properties.getDefaultSchema());
    liquibase.setDropFirst(this.properties.isDropFirst());
    liquibase.setShouldRun(this.properties.isEnabled());
    return liquibase;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("SampleDataJpaApplication");
    SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication();
    springApplication.run(SampleDataJpaApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

but it is failing with the message.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sampleDataJpaApplication': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field:
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties
>   sample.data.jpa.SampleDataJpaApplication.properties; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field:
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties
>   sample.data.jpa.SampleDataJpaApplication.properties; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Please provide the inputs here, why i am getting this exception or Is there any any other available way to override the same class so that i can change the changeLog property of liquibase properties.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the exact runtime path to your change log is, but why don't you just use the "liquibase.*" properties in `application.properties`? You should be able to leave out the `Liquibase` `@Bean` and let Boot do it for you.

If you prefer to add you own  `Liquibase` `@Bean` then take the hint and make sure you define a `LiquibaseProperties` bean as well (e.g. by declaring `@EnableConfigurationProperties(LiquibaseProperties.class)`).

Comment: Hi Dave,   Thanks for the information. I used liquibase.changeLog=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml in application.properties and it worked for me that's great.       It means, i can set the value of any property of any bean in my class path by mentioning the same in application.properties?